# free space not appearing in disk utility + multiple free spaces showing up in diskutil

Tags: macos, disk-utility

I recently tried to install asahi linux on my mac, but I installed the wrong version, so I used disk utility and wiped the partition, I then did a series of actions which i do not remember the entirety of but involved gdisk and turning the empty partitions into free space.

I somehow ended up with two separate free spaces showing up in diskutil, with the 9.2GB free space not showing up in disk utility.

[image]

Only the diskutil terminal command

[image]

Is there any way to resolve this or merge these two empty spaces together?